# Filterable Portfolio in two Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, portfolio

I'm with jquery or javascript in the very beginning, but I want to create a filterable portfolio on my site. On the top there are Filter Categories, wich should filter all thumbnails.

These Thumbnails are in a list (ul, li), and below there are certain Divs with the contents of this 5 Thumbnails. Then there are some thumbails in a list again and also again Divs with the Content of these Thumbnails.

My Code looks like this:

Filter-Categories // Navigation

```
<ul class="portfolio-filter">
<li><a data-rel="all" class="folio-btn active" href="#all">Alle</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="print" class="folio-btn" href="#print">Print</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="web" id="web" class="folio-btn" href="#web">Web</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="flash" id="flash" class="folio-btn" href="#flash">Flash</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="3d" id="3d" class="folio-btn" href="#3d">3D</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="grafik" id="grafik" class="folio-btn" href="#grafik">Grafik</a></li>
</ul>
```

Divs with Thumbnails:

```
<div class="projekte">
<ul class="stage">
<li class="pgrid web" id="ppreview1"><img src="preview-portfolio.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"><div id="poverlay1" class="overlay"><span><span class="plogo"><img src="img/desktop/small-logo-white.svg" width="30%" height="auto"></span>Projektname</span></div></li>            
<li class="pgrid web" id="ppreview2"><img src="preview-portfolio.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"><div id="poverlay2" class="overlay"><span><span class="plogo"><img src="img/desktop/small-logo-white.svg" width="30%" height="auto"></span>Projektname</span></div></li>
<li class="pgrid web" id="ppreview3"><img src="preview-portfolio.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"><div id="poverlay3" class="overlay"><span><span class="plogo"><img src="img/desktop/small-logo-white.svg" width="30%" height="auto"></span>Projektname</span></div></li>
<li class="pgrid web" id="ppreview4"><img src="preview-portfolio.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"><div id="poverlay4" class="overlay"><span><span class="plogo"><img src="img/desktop/small-logo-white.svg" width="30%" height="auto"></span>Projektname</span></div></li>
<li class="pgrid web" id="ppreview5"><img src="preview-portfolio.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"><div id="poverlay5" class="overlay"><span><span class="plogo"><img src="img/desktop/small-logo-white.svg" width="30%" height="auto"></span>Projektname</span></div></li>
</ul>

<div with content of thumbnail 1></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 2></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 3></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 4></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 5></div>

<ul class="stage">
<li more thumbnails></li>
<li more thumbnails></li>
<li more thumbnails></li>
<li more thumbnails></li>
<li more thumbnails></li>
</ul>

<div with content of thumbnail 6></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 7></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 8></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 9></div>
<div with content of thumbnail 10></div>
</div>
```

So I have two lines of Thumbnails with Div boxes below them, which show the content of the thumbnails on click. Now I want to sort all thumbnails in both ul's when I click one of the categories on top. Is that in any way possible?

I hope you understand what I mean... If you need more information, just ask!

Greetings!

Comment: Try to add a specific class to each element as a tag or key and when you select the filter, hide all the elements with that specific tag/key.

Answer (score 1):

Add a attribute to your div with the same name as your `a` data-rel to connect them.

See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1drxa25/1/)

```
jQuery('.portfolio-filter li a').on('click', function(event){
    var dataRel = jQuery(this).attr('data-rel');
    if (dataRel == 'all') {
        jQuery('div').slideDown();
    } else {
        jQuery('div[data-rel="'+dataRel+'"]').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<ul id="example2">
<li><a data-rel="all" class="folio-btn active" href="#all">Alle</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="print" class="folio-btn" href="#print">Print</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="web" id="web" class="folio-btn" href="#web">Web</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="flash" id="flash" class="folio-btn" href="#flash">Flash</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="3d" id="3d" class="folio-btn" href="#3d">3D</a></li>
<li><a data-rel="grafik" id="grafik" class="folio-btn" href="#grafik">Grafik</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting in your answer, but I'm not 100% sure if it actually answers the question.